# how to call SailsJs controller function from ExpressJs router?

Tags: sails.js

i want to call UserController from express js router
when i try to do it
i got Users.find is not a function
is this possible?

I want to integrations of express and sails same project

within single port without api call

like
router.get('/users',UserController.find(req,res));

Answer (score 0):

@gaurav checkout: https://github.com/neonexus/sails-react-bootstrap-webpack

Most importunely: /config/routes.js